# How to wait on an asio::awaitable?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, coroutine, c++-coroutine

Most coroutines work with a form of `std::future`-like types that also have a non-coroutine interface: One can wait on a future (`std::future::wait_for`) or get its underlying value / exception (`std::future::get`).

On the other hand, `asio::awaitable` doesn't seem to have these functionalities, as if one could only `co_await` on it.

So is it possible to wait on a `asio::awaitable`? or query for its state / value?